# Connect QEMU-KVM VMs using vhost-user-client and ovs-dpdk

Tags: overlay, kvm, dpdk, openvswitch, virtual-network

My goal is to connect two QEMU-KVM VMs on an overlay network. Each VM is running on a separate physical host and must have a static IP on the network 10.0.0.0/24. To achieve this goal, I want to use an OVS bridge with DPDK. I want to use the vhost-user-client protocol to connect the OVS bridge with the VMs.

My physical setup is the following: two physical machines equipped with a Mellanox ConnectX6-DX, and connected back-to-back (no physical switch). What I want to achieve is this:

```
+------------------+            +------------------+
| HOST_1           |            | HOST_2           |
|                  |            |                  |
|  +------------+  |            |  +------------+  |
|  | VM_1       |  |            |  | VM_2       |  |
|  |            |  |            |  |            |  |
|  | +--------+ |  |            |  | +--------+ |  |
|  | | ens_2  | |  |            |  | | ens_2  | |  |
|  | |10.0.0.1| |  |            |  | |10.0.0.2| |  |
|  +-+---+----+-+  |            |  +-+---+----+-+  |
|        |         |            |        |         | 
|  vhost-client-1  |            |  vhost-client-1  |
|        |         |            |        |         |
|  +-----+------+  |            |  +-----+------+  |
|  |  bridge    |  |            |  |  bridge    |  |
|  |    br0     |  |            |  |    br0     |  |
|  |192.168.57.1|  |            |  |192.168.57.2|  |
|  +-----+------+  |            |  +-----+------+  |
|        |         |            |        |         |
|    +---+---      |            |    +---+---+     |
|    | dpdk0 |     |            |    | dpdk0 |     |
+----+---+--+------+            +----+---+---+-----+
         |                               |
         +-------------------------------+
```

I successfully created the OVS bridge (here, br0) and the DPDK port (here, dpdk0). On each physical machine, I am able to ping the bridge on the other machine. Then, I created a vhost-user-client port and attached it to the bridge. On each guest, I assigned a static IP according to the above picture, and the *ens2* interface is up.

However, at this point I am not able to ping VM2 from VM1 or vice-versa. It seems like no traffic is exchanged through the vhost-client port at all. Ping fails with the *Destination Host Unreachable* message.

Some useful information:

**ovs-vsctl show**

```
Bridge br0
        datapath_type: netdev
        Port br0
            Interface br0
                type: internal
        Port dpdk0
            Interface dpdk0
                type: dpdk
                options: {dpdk-devargs="0000:01:00.0"}
        Port vhost-client-1
            Interface vhost-client-1
                type: dpdkvhostuserclient
                options: {vhost-server-path="/tmp/vhost-client-1"}
    ovs_version: "2.16.1"
```

**ovs-vsctl -- --columns=name,ofport list Interface**

```
name                : br0
ofport              : 65534

name                : dpdk0
ofport              : 6

name                : vhost-client-1
ofport              : 2
```

**ovs-ofctl dump-flows br0**

```
cookie=0x0, duration=104.689s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, in_port="vhost-client-1" actions=output:dpdk0
cookie=0x0, duration=99.573s, table=0, n_packets=4, n_bytes=924, in_port=dpdk0 actions=output:"vhost-client-1"
```

**ovs-ofctl show br0**

```
OFPT_FEATURES_REPLY (xid=0x2): dpid:0000b8cef64def2e
n_tables:254, n_buffers:0
capabilities: FLOW_STATS TABLE_STATS PORT_STATS QUEUE_STATS ARP_MATCH_IP
actions: output enqueue set_vlan_vid set_vlan_pcp strip_vlan mod_dl_src mod_dl_dst mod_nw_src mod_nw_dst mod_nw_tos mod_tp_src mod_tp_dst
 2(vhost-client-1): addr:00:00:00:00:00:00
     config:     0
     state:      LINK_DOWN
     speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 6(dpdk0): addr:b8:ce:f6:4d:ef:2e
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    AUTO_NEG
     speed: 0 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
 LOCAL(br0): addr:b8:ce:f6:4d:ef:2e
     config:     0
     state:      0
     current:    10MB-FD COPPER
     speed: 10 Mbps now, 0 Mbps max
OFPT_GET_CONFIG_REPLY (xid=0x4): frags=normal miss_send_len=0
```

**Libvirt XML configuration** (relevant parts)

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>ubuntu-server</name>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <interface type='vhostuser'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:16:a5:76'/>
      <source type='unix' path='/tmp/vhost-client-1' mode='server'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

Which configuration option am I missing? I have followed several guides but still I am unable to route any traffic between my VMs.

I suspect that the problem is related to the *LINK_DOWN* status of the vhost-client-1 port as reported by the **ovs-ofctl show** command. I've tried to set that status as UP with the command **ovs-ofctl mod-port br0 vhost-client-1 up**. Even though the command did not fail, nothing changed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: In edit of VM-instance, when you add dpdkports to VM. Can we give any random mac ? ( if not which mac is that ?) and any free slot ( if not which slot)?. I edited my VM with NUMA ( under CPU), added 2 dpdkuserport and <memoryBacking> unit and rebooted my VM but it didn't show new interfaces. Can u pls help me?

Comment: You can omit the whole line with the MAC address and KVM will create that for you. For the PCI slot, just pick one that is not currently in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to solve my problem. Vipin's answer was useful, but did not solve the issue. The configuration option I was missing was the `numa` option within the `cpu` element.

I post the working configuration file just in case it is useful for other people. The first part is about memory backing (under the `domain` element):

```
  <memory unit='KiB'>[VM memory size]</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>[VM memory size]</currentMemory>
  <memoryBacking>
    <hugepages>
      <page size='2048' unit='KiB'/>
    </hugepages>
    <locked/>
    <source type='file'/>
    <access mode='shared'/>
    <allocation mode='immediate'/>
    <discard/>
  </memoryBacking>
```

But we also needed the `numa` configuration, even if our machine had just one processor:

```
<cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>qemu64</model>
    <feature policy='require' name='x2apic'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='lahf_lm'/>
    <feature policy='disable' name='svm'/>
    <numa>
      <cell id='0' cpus='0-1' memory='[VM memory size]' unit='KiB' memAccess='shared'/>
    </numa>
</cpu>
```

Comment: it is always good to hear people find solutions and share the same to help others. But you did fail to mention the suggested answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064744/cannot-use-testpmd-to-send-pkts-to-vm-in-qemu-process-though-virtio/70081798?noredirect=1#comment123885889_70081798 for your reference there were mention of NUMA setting right in the answer (especially in the comment). `Wonder why you had missed to mention that out`.

Answer (score 0):

`suspect that the problem is related to the LINK_DOWN status of the vhost-client-1 port`

[Answer] Yes, the cause for packet not reaching VM is OVS sees the interface down. Even with the presence of a rule to forward traffic from dpdk0 to vhost-client-1 the packets will be dropped.

The primary cause of `link not up` can be due to the qemu configuration `memory backed` with ***hugepages*** not being used. Vhost-USER port created by DPDK=OVS resides on the huge page memory area and access to the same is required.

A similar [DPDK-QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70064744/cannot-use-testpmd-to-send-pkts-to-vm-in-qemu-process-though-virtio/70081798?noredirect=1#comment123885889_70081798) StackOverflow address the use of viritio-client (via cmdline). So please adapt the settings shared into the link to `virsh xml`

template:

```
<memory unit='KiB'>[VM memory size]</memory> 
<currentMemory unit='KiB'>[VM memory size]</currentMemory>
<memoryBacking> <hugepages/> </memoryBacking>
```

[EDIT-1] Based on the information shared from @ellere `Vipin's answer was useful, but did not solve the issue. The configuration option I was missing was the numa option within the cpu element`.

[image]

depending whether the memory used is from NUMA-SOCKET please add appropriate tag